# How summarize list by mutiple property

Tags: c#, linq

i have a list like:

```
List<ClassName> item= new List<ClassName>();
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Typ= 1,
    Name= A,
    Amount = 5
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Typ= 2,
    Name= B,
    Amount = 3
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Typ= 1,
    Name= A,
    Amount = 3
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Typ= 1,
    Name= C,
    Amount = 3
});
```

I want to summarize it by the same Typ and Name, or maybe by even more same properties besides Amount. How can i do it?

Comment: Are you looking for [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: In case GroupBy doesn't answer your question, tell us what you mean by "summarize a list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by 'Group By' in LINQ.

```
 var summarizedList = list.GroupBy(item => new { item.Typ, item.Name }) 
            .Select(group => new ClassName
            {
                Typ = group.Key.Typ,
                Name = group.Key.Name,
                Amount = group.Sum(item => item.Amount)
            })
            .ToList();
```